# What's the hardest wearing multibraid rope type?

Tags: ropes, boats, sailing

I'm looking to replace the line in a traveller on a catamaran and I need a very hard wearing sheath due to the nature of the setup. Is dyneema the way to go here?

Comment: I'm not an expert in this but I'd say dyneema wouldn't be a great choice. Dyneema is not very abrasive resistant (in general). It's main properties are good strength to weigh ratio. I'm not a sailor though, I'm looking at this from a climbing point of view

Comment: yes sailors or boaters have attempted many many times to get a boating specific stack exchange site off the ground but unfortunately couldn't get past the activity levels required

Comment: @Liam I believe it is exactly the other way around: Dyneema is the most abrasion resistant: See this question about the same thing but related to climbing: https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/7790/relative-abraision-resistance-of-dyneema-slings-vs-an-average-dynamic-climbing-r However I don't believe this is a duplicate, as this question is specific to sailing and multibraid (whatever that is, not a sailor here).

Answer (score 5):

Dyneema is the most hard wearing, however if you need it to run through any friction grip or clutch it is not a good choice as it is very smooth and shiny.

Polyester really is the cost-effective, UV resistant and strong, especially when paired with a Dyneema core, so this is probably the way to go, although you could look at Cordura as an alternative.